# Wordpress - MYSQL Sleep Connection

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am having slowness and fall on my wordpress website.
When the number of connections exceeds 100, my site is extremely slow and unstable.

Looking at the MYSQL statistic I saw that of the 100 connections most are in sleep for a long time (4000s +).

**How can I kill these connections?** **How can I decrease the number of sleeping connections?**

Comment: i would first check if this query `SELECT * FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND = 'sleep' AND INFO LIKE '%SLEEP%'` returns anny results.. if it does there is SQL injection on your wordpress site and a attacker might included MySQL injection vectors like `' OR SLEEP(10000)`

Comment: And if it's empty?

Comment: I would save the current unique queries with `SELECT DISTINCT INFO FROM information_schema.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND = 'sleep'` to check later on with EXPLAIN.. the queries might need optimization like indexes.

Comment: All connections are as sleep, and your information is set to null.